# String encoding in android

Tags: java, android

I need to encode string in android but it doesn't work . I don't know which encoding should I do .I need to display **"Ruzyn\u011b (PRG)"** on textview but it display same as look without encoding .Is there any help ??

Comment: String s="Ruzyn\u011b (PRG)";

s=new String{s.getBytes(),"UTF-8"} ;

TextView t=new TextView(this);

t.setText(s);

But it dislay same as in String s without encoding .

Comment: If you defined `s` exactly as you showed, then it's already a valid, correct `String`. If you only want to display it on the UI, then you don't need any kind of encoding at all.

Comment: My guess: your Android device/emulator doesn't have the font to display the character in question.

Comment: Have you tried using the ISO-8859-1 encoding? I have created some applications that used French and it everything worked fine in ISO encoding. Characters such as ë à è ê ü amongst other

Comment: @Joachim Sauer is probably right, I didn't think about it beforehand but there's a strong possibility that it might be the case.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `s=new String (s.getBytes())`, do not use UTF-8.

Comment: still it display same like String s.

Comment: This is **at best** a no-op (i.e. it does nothing) and depending on the platform default encoding it might replace un-encodable characters with "?". Don't do this!